# VBA Reference Designators group by Prefix, using a filter but running into problem

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here is my code.  I am taking the following designators and shorthanding grouping them to AR2-AR4,AR15,AT3-AT4,C68,C76,C316,C319,FL14-FL18,J1-J6,L2-5,etc.  This is all working good except when the filter applies "L" in which it returns FL14,FL15,FL16,FL17,FL8,L2,L3,L4,L5.  I need a way to do an exact character match or something.

```
Sub FormatAsRanges()
    
        Dim Lne As String, arr, s
        Dim n As Long, v As Long, prev As Long, inRange As Boolean
        Dim test As String
        Dim x As Variant
        Dim filterarray As Variant
        inRange = False
    
        Lne = "AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4,AT3,AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14,FL15,FL16,FL17,FL18,FL6,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,L2,L3,L4,L5,T4,T5,T6,U38"
       
        arr = Split(Lne, ",") 'Break apart references into array items
        x = Prefix(arr) 'Get the Prefix's (AR,AT,C,FL,J,L,T,U)
        x = Split(x, ",") ' Split them in an array
        
    For j = 0 To UBound(x)
    
        inRange = False 'Initialize to False
        arr = Split(Lne, ",") ' Redifine arr since it is being filtered and use in the j loop for each prefix
        filterarray = Filter(arr, x(j)) ' Apply filter
        For i = 0 To UBound(filterarray)
              filterarray(i) = Replace(filterarray(i), x(j), "")
        Next i
        arr = ArraySort(filterarray)
        prev = -999 'dummy value
        For n = LBound(filterarray) To UBound(filterarray)
            v = CLng(filterarray(n))
            If v - prev = 1 Then 'starting or continuing a range?
                inRange = True   'wait until range ends before adding anything
            Else
                If inRange Then           'ending a range ?
                    s = s & "-" & x(j) & prev 'close out current range with previous item
                    inRange = False
                End If
                s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ",", "") & x(j) & v  'add the current item
            End If
            prev = v
        Next n
        If inRange Then s = s & "-" & x(j) & prev 'close out last item if in a range
        
        Debug.Print s
        s = Empty
        filterarray = Empty
    Next j
End Sub
    
Function ArraySort(MyArray As Variant)
        Dim First As Long, last As Long
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp
        First = LBound(MyArray)
        last = UBound(MyArray)
        For i = First To last - 1
            For j = i + 1 To last
                If CLng(MyArray(i)) > CLng(MyArray(j)) Then
                    Temp = MyArray(j)
                    MyArray(j) = MyArray(i)
                    MyArray(i) = Temp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        ArraySort = MyArray
End Function
    
    
'get the character prefix (up to the first digit)
Public Function Prefix(a As Variant)
        Dim rv As String, c As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, Prf As String
        Dim flt(10) As String
        
    Prf = "*" 'Initialize string
    k = 0 'initialize
       
            For j = 0 To UBound(a)
             If InStr(a(j), Prf) Then
                
                'Debug.Print "Yes"
               
              Else
                   
                Prf = Empty
                For i = 0 To Len(a(j))
           
                    c = Mid(a(j), i + 1, 1)
                    If c Like "#" Then
                    
                    Exit For
                    
                    Else
                        rv = rv & c
                
              End If
            
            
            Next i
          Prf = rv
       
       flt(k) = Prf
       k = k + 1
       rv = Empty
       End If
        
    
    Next j
    
    For l = 0 To UBound(flt) 'Output as string so to define an array that is the correct size in the main program
      If flt(l) Like "?" Then
             rtn = rtn + flt(l) + ","
        ElseIf flt(l) Like "??" Then
             rtn = rtn + flt(l) + ","
            ElseIf flt(l) Like "???" Then
            
                    rtn = rtn + flt(l) + ","
          
        End If
            
    Next l
    rtn = Left(rtn, Len(rtn) - 1)
    Prefix = rtn
End Function
```

Comment: "to do an exact character match or something" is something completely unclear. At least, for me... Do you expect us to deduce from your code, which "running into problem" what you really want accomplishing? Nobody likes wasting his time with such an activity... I would suggest you to edit the question and try accurately explaining what you are trying to do, against what you obtains.

Comment: Are you trying to regroup contiguous ranges in the same range? You can do this using Union: `Set r = Range("AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4,AT3,AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14,FL15,FL16,FL17,FL18,FL6,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,L2,L3,L4,L5,T4,T5,T6,U38"): Set r = Union(r, r): Debug.Print r.Address(False, False)` will return `AR15,AR2:AR4,AT3:AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14:FL18,FL6,J1:J6,L2:L5,T4:T6,U38`

Comment: The code works fine stripping off the prefix with numbers remaining.  Like when the filter is applied "AR" it will find only the references with AR in this case AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4.  Then it removes AR and returns the numbers which go into a bubble sort so it comes out of the bubble sort as 2,3,4,15.  Then it goes back to the main program for ranges in this case 2,3,4 and puts the prefix AR back on and shows AR2-AR4 and then since 15 is by itself it comes out AR15.  So the total line returned is AR2-AR4,AR5.  Everything is fine on the filter until the "L".  Since "L" is in "FL" it returns...

Comment: this too and I need a way for it to discern L prefix form an FL prefix.

Comment: filterarray = Filter(arr, x(j))  is the only real thing I am after.  When I pass a prefix into this filter I want to make it smarter.

Comment: `Filter` is rarely that useful, becuase it always filters on substrings.  You should write a function which will filter on *prefix* and return an array of only those types of matches.

Comment: Tried your code. When it filters on "L", I get F6, etc. - it drops the "L" and then "type mismatch" error. Error is introduced with the Replace() function. You are using undeclared variables. Should include Option Explicit in module header.

Comment: It is stripping of the prefix to return an integer.  FL should not be in the list but the filter is only doing what it can do.  Anyway the error is in the bubble sort because it is only looking for integers not character integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move more of the code into separate methods:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim Lne As String, arr, allPrefixes, arrFilt, arrSorted, s, prefix
    
    Lne = "AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4,AT3,AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14,FL15," & _
          "FL16,FL17,FL18,FL6,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,L2,L3,L4,L5,T4,T5,T6,U38"
   
    arr = Split(Lne, ",")        'split to an array
    
    allPrefixes = UniquePrefixes(arr) 'All unique character prefixes
    Debug.Print "All prefixes: " & Join(allPrefixes, ",")
    
    'process each prefix in turn
    For Each prefix In allPrefixes
    
        arrFilt = FilterPrefixNumbers(arr, prefix)        'items for this prefix (numbers only)
        Debug.Print , "'" & prefix & "' items:", Join(arrFilt, ",")
        arrSorted = ArraySort(arrFilt)                    'numeric parts, sorted ascending
        Debug.Print , "Sorted:", Join(arrSorted, ",")
        
        s = s & iif(s<>"", ",", "") & FormatAsRanges(arrSorted, prefix)
        'Debug.Print FormatAsRanges(arrSorted, prefix)
    
    Next prefix

    Debug.Print s 'the whole thing
End Sub
    
Function FormatAsRanges(arr, prefix) As String

    Dim s As String, n As Long, v As Long, prev As Long, inRange As Boolean

    prev = -999 'dummy value
    For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        v = CLng(arr(n))
        If v - prev = 1 Then 'starting or continuing a range?
            inRange = True   'wait until range ends before adding anything
        Else
            If inRange Then           'ending a range ?
                s = s & "-" & prefix & prev   'close out current range with previous item
                inRange = False
            End If
            s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ",", "") & prefix & v  'add the current item
        End If
        prev = v
    Next n
    If inRange Then s = s & "-" & prefix & prev 'close out last item if in a range
    
    FormatAsRanges = s
End Function


Function ArraySort(MyArray As Variant)
    Dim First As Long, last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp
    First = LBound(MyArray)
    last = UBound(MyArray)
    For i = First To last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To last
            If CLng(MyArray(i)) > CLng(MyArray(j)) Then
                Temp = MyArray(j)
                MyArray(j) = MyArray(i)
                MyArray(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ArraySort = MyArray
End Function
    
'return an array *of numbers* from all items in "arr" with the given prefix
Function FilterPrefixNumbers(arr, prefix)
    Dim rv(), e, n As Long
    ReDim rv(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    n = LBound(arr)
    For Each e In arr
        If GetPrefix(CStr(e)) = prefix Then
            rv(n) = Replace(e, prefix, "") 'return just the numeric parts...
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next e
    ReDim Preserve rv(LBound(arr) To n - 1) 'shrink to remove any empty slots
    FilterPrefixNumbers = rv
End Function

'all unique character prefixes
Function UniquePrefixes(arr)
    Dim dict, e
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each e In arr
        dict(GetPrefix(CStr(e))) = True
    Next e
    UniquePrefixes = dict.keys
End Function

'get the character prefix (all non-digit characters preceding the first digit)
Function GetPrefix(v As String) As String
    Dim rv As String, c As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        c = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            rv = rv & c
        End If
    Next i
    GetPrefix = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Tim,  This works great.  Only thing I would need is for all of it returned to one line.  I have been trying but it doesn't look good as the ones with a single common prefix.

Comment: See my edit above - it's not a huge leap to put it all together.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  t may not be a leap for you but it is for me.  I am studying what you did though so I don't have to ask so many questions next time.

Comment: Tim an off question  can dictionary keys be output to a query in access, like 1 row per key.  Can't find anything on it.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking - are you talking about inserting data, or querying?

Comment: I would like to know about querying.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate Filter() and Replace() functions. Given that input data is already sorted alphabetically by prefix, following revised procedure works:

```
Sub FormatAsRanges()
    
    Dim Lne As String, arr, s
    Dim n As Long, v As Long, prev As Long 
    Dim inRange As Boolean
    Dim j As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim filterarray As Variant

    Lne = "AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4,AT3,AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14,FL15,FL16,FL17,FL18,FL6,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,L2,L3,L4,L5,T4,T5,T6,U38"
    arr = Split(Lne, ",") 'Break apart references into array items
    x = Split(Prefix(arr), ",") 'Get the Prefix's (AR,AT,C,FL,J,L,T,U)
        
    For j = 0 To UBound(x)
        inRange = False 'Initialize to False
        Do While arr(i) Like x(j) & "*" And i <= UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) Like x(j) & "*" Then
                s = s & Mid(arr(i), Len(x(j)) + 1) & ","
                If i = UBound(arr) Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        filterarray = ArraySort(Split(s, ","))
        prev = -999 'dummy value
        s = ""
        For n = LBound(filterarray) To UBound(filterarray)
            v = CLng(filterarray(n))
            If v - prev = 1 Then 'starting or continuing a range?
                inRange = True   'wait until range ends before adding anything
            Else
                If inRange Then           'ending a range ?
                    s = s & "-" & x(j) & prev 'close out current range with previous item
                    inRange = False
                End If
                s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ",", "") & x(j) & v  'add the current item
            End If
            prev = v
        Next n
        If inRange Then s = s & "-" & x(j) & prev 'close out last item if in a range
        Debug.Print s
        s = Empty
        filterarray = Empty
    Next j
End Sub
```